# What does a north-east pointing arrow symbol (↗) stand for in mathematics?

Tags: random, convergence-divergence

Is there a canonical definition of "↗"?

I've seen it in a formulation of the Monotone convergence theorem as follows:

> Let X and X<sub>n</sub> be random variables for which X<sub>n</sub> ↗ X ...

from which it would seem that "X<sub>n</sub> ↗ X" means two things:

1. The sequence X<sub>n</sub> converges to X, and
2. X<sub>n+1</sub> is greater or equal to X<sub>n</sub> almost surely

although it is not clear which type of convergence is assumed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This notation does indeed indicate convergence where $X_{n+1}\ge X_n$, but what *kind* of convergence needs to be specified, or it should be clear from the context. Likewise, whether the inequality is everywhere or just a.e. will depend on context, and should be specified if there is reasonable doubt. This notation can even be used if $X_n$ is a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, with $\ge$ meaning that the difference is positive semidefinite. In short, it can be used in any context where there is both an ordering and a notion of convergence.

Comment: Thank you, Harald, for this comprehensive answer!